# How can I create an Airflow DAG that incoporates python script that processes images?

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a python script that processes images through different functions and I need to create a pipeline in airflow to have it set out.

The .py script has a bunch of functions and imports created at the begining then has a main() function defined that calls all the function above and looks something like this:

```
def main():
processed_data = process_images(image_ids)

save_processed_data(processed_data)



# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
parser = set_arg_parser()
args = parser.parse_args()

data_dir = args.data_dir
height = args.height
width = args.width
n_aug = args.n_aug
proc_lim = args.proc_lim

images_outdir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'processed_images')
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(images_outdir), exist_ok=True)

labels_outdir =  os.path.join(data_dir, 'labels')
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(labels_outdir), exist_ok=True)

ids_outdir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'metadata')
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(ids_outdir), exist_ok=True)


images_outpath_prefix = os.path.join(images_outdir, 'X')
labels_outpath_prefix = os.path.join(labels_outdir, 'processed')
ids_outpath_prefix = os.path.join(ids_outdir, 'processed_ids')

df_labels = get_df_labels()
image_ids = get_image_ids(df_labels)

if proc_lim is not None:
    image_ids = image_ids[:proc_lim]

main()
```

Where all the functions are created before and the main() functions calls out the processing. My question is how could I structure this in an airflow DAG? Unfortunately I have not much experience in creating dags that manage this sort of scripts, is there a way to create a DAG for this?

Thank you

Comment: Your indentation isn't accurately.

Comment: Yea, sorry about that, just wanted to give a brief description on what is actually going on.

Comment: What is `data_dir` exactly? Is this path available inside the Airflow worker, or is it a remote path somewhere else? Airflow can do exactly what you need, have you looked at the [TaskFlow API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial_taskflow_api.html) (if you are using Airflow 2)? This API was designed exactly for this kind of workflow.